# Find all occurrences of object instantiation in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Something that I miss from Java is the ability to find all object instantiations in the project simply by searching for the `new` keyword, however Kotlin doesn't have this keyword and there's no way to do it with string search. Is there any way to find instantiations in Kotlin?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you want to use the found instantiantions for something or if you just need to count them, but, if this is the case, then you may simply use the `Find in Path` tool in IntelliJ/Android Studio with the `Regex` option checked and search for this: `(\(|\[|\{|( ))([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)+\(`, which matches `CamelCased` strings after `(`, `[`, `{` or `[space]` and are followed by a `(`, just like we call constructors in Kotlin if we are using a standard formatting design.